# Undefined offset and non-object in obtaining the number of category posts

Tags: wordpress

In the standard menu class (**walker_nav_menu** **start_el**), I added my code, which shows how many posts in categories:

```
$PostsCount= '';
if($item->object == 'category'){
    $cats = get_categories(array('include'=>$item->object_id));
    if($cats[0]->count>0) {
        $PostsCount='<div>'.$cats[0]->count.'</div>';
    }
}

$item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after . $PostsCount;
```

The script works and displays, but in PHP queries 2 errors:

**Notice: Undefined offset: 0**

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**

for this line: `if($cats[0]->count>0) {`

I can not understand why it's not right... How can I correct these errors?

**-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-**

**The question is settled. If anyone is interested, here is the solution:**

```
$countPostsCat = '';
if($item->object == 'category'){
    $cats = get_categories(array('include'=>$item->object_id));
    if ($cats) {
        $cats[0]->count>0;
        $countPostsCat='<count>'.$cats[0]->count.'</count>';
    }
}
```

Comment: if you added the code into some loop, it may not get properties you want. check values before using them. use `empty()`,`isset()`,`is_object()` functions

Comment: put print_r($cats); under the set of $cats, what is the result, can you add it to here?

Comment: `Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 4 [name] => name [slug] => slug [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 4 [taxonomy] => category [description] => description [parent] => 1 [count] => 3 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 4 [category_count] => 3 [category_description] => category_description [cat_name] => cat_name [category_nicename] => category_nicename [category_parent] => 1 ) )`
example of one output category